Proof that metric compatible covariant derivative on Riemannian manifold is unique.
I'm following along with Wald's book on General Relativity and I have a question about the proof that the derivative operator is unique, given a connection and that it is compatible with the connection (along with assuming torsion free). In Wald's proof he shows that the difference tensor $C^c_{ab}$ (defined as the difference between two derivative operators $\nabla '$ and $\nabla$) satisfies the condition
$$ C^c_{ab} = \frac{1}{2} g^{cd} \big( \nabla_a g_{bd} + \nabla_b g_{ad} - \nabla_d g_{ab}\big)
$$
He then goes on to say that since this equation has a unique solution it implies that the derivative operator is also unique. Now, there's a pretty good chance that I am not understanding what he is saying, or his proof. However, I'd like to start with the assumption that we have two derivative operators, which are metric compatible and torsion free, and then show that their difference is zero. Can anyone give me a little help getting started with this?

This looks like a suboptimal proof. You can instead read the more standard proof, say, in do Carmo's book.

You haven’t stated all the details. This formula holds only if $\nabla’$ is assumed to be torsion free and compatible. If $\nabla$ is too, then the right side is zero because $\nabla g=0$.

@Deane Yes, but I still don't see how that shows $\nabla$ is unique (given it is metric compatible and torsion free). If it is unique then if I take two derivative operators $\nabla$ and $\nabla'$ that satisfies those conditions then $\nabla - \nabla'$ should be identically zero. Can you give me a hint for how to show this? I can't find a source that explicitly shows this.

If the difference between the two operators is zero, then they are equal.

Yes, that is why I am trying to show that their difference is zero, in general. I don't see how Wald/your argument gives that. Could you elaborate a little?

Under the assumption that $\nabla'$ and $\nabla$ are both torsion free and compatible with the metric, the equation above holds and the right side  is equal to zero. Therefore, so is the left side. Therefore, $\nabla' - \nabla = C = 0$.

Wald's proof proves only uniqueness. The standard proof proves both existence and uniqueness. Let $\nabla$ be any torsion free connection. Define $C$ using $\nabla$ and $g$ as above. Define $\nabla' = \nabla + C$. It is easily checked that $\nabla'$ is torsion free and compatible with the metric. Any other connection $\nabla''$ that is torsion free and compatible with the metric has to satisfy the same equation. Therefore, $\nabla'' = \nabla'$.

Thanks @Deane for the additional information! I still need to ponder it a bit though. Also, Wald proves existence earlier on in the section, I think.

One more comment. Looking at questions you've asked, it seems like you're trying to learn general relativity without having studied carefully Riemannian geometry. Although in principle this is possible, it is far better to learn Riemannian geometry really really well before you try to tackle general relativity.

Thank you for the advice too.
